# The list it empty after the each time I choose the same option

Tags: python, list

Each time I choose option 1 it deletes the previous input so I always get success and don't get book already exists. How to fix it?

Thank you!

```
while True:
    option=int(input("enter an option\n"))
    list=[]
    Library=[]
    if option==1:
      nameBook=input("enter name to the book\n")
      list.append(nameBook)
      for nameBook in list:
        if nameBook not in Library:
          Library.append(nameBook)
          print("success")
        else:
          print("book already exist")
```

Comment: Assuming `list=[]` is inside the loop, this is your problem. You reinitialize it every iteration.

Comment: what to do in order that this would not happen? @guy

Comment: Move it outside the loop.

Comment: As @Guy has pointed out move the list initialization before the loop, i.e before the `while` statement.

Answer (score 3):

You need to put your list you named list outside of the while loop.

```py
list = []
while True:
    option = int(input("enter an option\n"))

    Library = []
    if option == 1:
        nameBook = input("enter name to the book\n")
        list.append(nameBook)
        for nameBook in list:
            if nameBook not in Library:
                Library.append(nameBook)
                print("success")
            else:
                print("book already exist")
```

Try this and you will see that "book already exist" will print if you try to put same book several times.

Please also note that it is highly not recommanded to call a list "list" as list is already a buil-in python object.